# Pandas Columns Not Getting Updated Correctly

Tags: pandas

I have selected movies dataset. That has one field "Revenue (Millions)". For some movies data in this field is nan.

I am trying to replace the "Revenue (Millions)" field if it is blank with the median of "Revenue (Millions)" of the same "Genre" - By the way I have renamed the columns and also made all the column names in small case. In this my "Revenue (Millions)" field is getting replaced with the median but it is the median of the first "Genre" selected. i.e. if "Genre" is "Comedy"  and "Revenue (Millions) is nan then median of "Revenue (Millions)" of all the "Comedy" movies should replace the nan value.

Code is mentioned below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objs as go 

data = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/insaid2018/Term-1/master/Data/Projects/1000%20movies%20data.csv')

data.rename(columns={'Runtime (Minutes)': 'Durinmins','Revenue (Millions)': 'Revinmil'},inplace=True)

data.columns = map(str.lower,data.columns)

lstGnr = []
mySet = {}
for (row,col) in data.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(col.revinmil):
        lstGnr.append(col.genre)
mySet = set(lstGnr)
lstGnr = list(mySet)

for (row,col) in data.iterrows():
    if col.genre in lstGnr:
        if pd.isnull(col.revinmil):
            tempVal = (data[(data['genre'] == col.genre) & (data['revinmil'].notnull())]).median()[['revinmil']]
            data['revinmil'].replace(to_replace=col.revinmil,value=tempVal[0],inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `transform(`) to get the median of each group and use it to fill the NAs in a column like this -

```
data["revinmil"] = data.groupby("genre")['revinmil'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
```

Comment: This function is not working well. It is picking up value of "Rank" field and replacing the null values in "revinmil".

Comment: This works... Thanks for your timely help.